# Anchor link loading wrong position

Tags: html, css, wordpress, scroll, anchor

My anchors are working perfectly fine when there referring to a anchor on the same page. But when there referring to another page, they load in with an offset.

The anchor is referred to as;

```
<a name="featuredwork">
```

The link is;

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/home/#featuredwork"><strong>FEATURED WORK</strong></a>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Here in the second anchor tag "https://www.example.com/home/#featuredwork" you have mentioned #featuredwork. So by default the page will target to that related section.

Comment: Can you give a real example? As it is, we can't really answer you.. My guess is that there is content appended to the page on load, and if the case, there's nothing you can do about it

Comment: http://testx.dezestraver.nl/overflow

Comment: There is actually content that is loaded after the redirection to the anchor is done. Most probably by revolution slider. If you have full control over the site, your only possibility is to find which element takes more height than what is initially reserved, and add a CSS rule so that the height is the good one from the start

Comment: @Kaddath Can you show an example of what that css would look like?

Comment: @kaddath did you see the message above?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunetly i'm rather busy, due to the CMS and plugins styling, it can be complex to achieve. Helped to the amount i can, good luck for the rest..